# Android AdMob uses cpu in the background

Tags: android, admob, cpu

I have build an android app, that is using the Google AdMob advertising framework. I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 2.3.3 and AdMob 6.4.1.

Recently I experienced, that some kind of AdMob ads (like the ones for the Google Play Store, for example the "Deezer App") cause CPU usage, although the app is running in the background (lifecycle onStop()).

Other ads, that are more static and only have one picture, do not cause any cpu usage being in the background.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong? Or is it actually the AdMob framework that has a "bug"?

Answer (score 0):

stopLoading() on the AdMobView worked for me

Comment: I thought, that stopLoading() is used during the loading-process of the ad. But I experience the cpu usage although the ad is completely loaded. Just for the understanding: I fully load my app + the ad in the app, then hide the ap and then I can see, that the app causes cpu usage.

Comment: I assume the AdMob JS code does continuously keep doing some stuff. I haven't analysed that any more. That's what stopped.